# Button to view details in popup window not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm working with a Kendo UI Web grid. I've integrated a custom button used to display data into a popup window. The button was initially used in a command column. That worked flawlessly.

Now I've tried to place the same button within a regular column and nothing shows up. Doesn't even throw errors, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Any suggestions?

**Working Link from JSBin:**
http://jsbin.com/iJunOsa/8/edit

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>


  <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="territoriesTemplate">
    #for(var i = 0; i < Territories.length; i++){#
        <span>#:Territories[i].TerritoryDescription#</span>&nbsp;<button id="info-btn">Info</button><br />
    #}#
</script>

  <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="storesTemplate">
        #for(var i = 0; i < Territories.length; i++){#
           #for(var y = 0; y < Territories[i].TerritoryStores.length; y++) {#
                    <span>#:Territories[i].TerritoryStores[y].StoreName#</span>
             #}#
        #}#
</script>

  <div id="grid"></div>

  <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="view">
            <div id="details-container">
                    <label>Where is #= TerritoryDescription #?</label>
                    <p><strong>#= TerritoryDescription # is in blah blah blah...</strong></p>
                </div>
            </script>

  <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
                <div class="toolbar">
                  <input type="search" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Search" id="search" style="width: 200px"></input>
                </div>
          </script>  

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var data = [
  { "EmployeeId": 1, "FirstName": "Jim", "LastName": "Jones", "Territories": [{ "Id": 1, "TerritoryDescription": "Wilton","TerritoryStores": [{ "Id": 1, "StoreName": "Navarra" }] }] }
    ];
                $(document).ready(function () {
                var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: function(e) {                                
                              e.success(data);
                            },
                            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read") {
                                    for(var field in options) {
                                        if ($.isArray(options[field])){
                                            serializeArray(field, options[field], options);
                                        }                           
                                    }
                                }
                                return options;
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 10,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "EmployeeId",
                                fields: {
                                    EmployeeId: { type:"number" },
                                    FirstName: { type:"string" },
                                    LastName: { type:"string" },
                                    Territories: { defaultValue:[] },
                                    TerritoryStores: { defaultValue:[] }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    editable: false,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: {
                        pageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100]
                    },
                    //height: 500,
                    toolbar: kendo.template( $( "#template" ).html() ),
                    filterable: false,
                    columns: [
                                { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", filterable: false, sortable: true, width: "220px" },
                                { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", filterable: false, sortable: true, width: "220px" },
                                {
                                    field: "Territories",
                                    title: "Territory",
                                    template: kendo.template($("#territoriesTemplate").html()),
                                    sortable: true,
                                    width: "120px"
                                },                          
                                {
                                    field: "TerritoryStores",
                                    title: "Stores",
                                    template: kendo.template($("#storesTemplate").html()),
                                    sortable: false,
                                    width: "120px"
                                }]
                        }).data("kendoGrid");

                        //serialize as a string
                        function serializeArray(prefix, array, result) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                                if ($.isPlainObject(array[i])) {
                                    for (var property in array[i]) {
                                        result[prefix + "[" + i + "]." + property] = array[i][property];
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    result[prefix + "[" + i + "]"] = array[i];
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //autofilter search bar
                        var timeout;

                        $("#search").bind("keydown", function() {
                            var input = $(this);
                            clearTimeout(timeout);

                            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                                var text = input.val(),
                                    dataSource = grid.dataSource;        

                                if (text !== "") {
                                    dataSource.query({
                                        page: 1,
                                        filter: {
                                            field: "FirstName",
                                            value: text,
                                            operator: "contains"
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else  if (text === "" && dataSource.filter()) {
                                    dataSource.query({ filter: {}, page: 1, pageSize: 10 });
                                }        
                            }, 500);
                        });

                        wnd = $("#details")
                        .kendoWindow({
                            modal: true,
                            visible: false,
                            resizable: false,
                            width: 600,
                            height:250
                        }).data("kendoWindow");

                        detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#view").html());
                    });

                    $("#info-btn").bind("click", function showDetails(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                        wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
                        wnd.center().open();

                        wnd.setOptions({
                            title: dataItem.TerritoryDescription
                        });
                      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole bunch of problems; some of them:

1. when you're creating your details window, `$("#details")` is empty (so there never is a window)
2. you're trying to access `TerritoryDescription` on the `dataItem`, but it is a nested property
3. you're declaring the variable `grid` inside jQuery's ready function but try to access it outside of that context
4. you're trying to call `dataItem()` on `this` in the click handler, but in that context, `this` is the DOM element
5. you're binding your click handler for an id - this won't work for multiple rows (use a class instead)
6. you're binding your click handler at a time when the targeted elements don't exist yet - use [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `bind`

Somewhat improved [demo](http://jsbin.com/ISANaDoL/2/edit)

What you should do in the future to diagnose problems like these: log out your variables and see if they're defined as you expect them to be (or set breakpoints and debug).

Answer (score 0):

First of all put the next function inside the document ready:

```
$("#info-btn").bind("click", function showDetails(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                        wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
                        wnd.center().open();

                        wnd.setOptions({
                            title: dataItem.TerritoryDescription
                        });
                      });
```

But still throws some errors.